# How to add list datatype data to existing data frame in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I wanted to append list data to each row in the existing dataframe in pyspark.

```
data=[["sai",25],["praveen",25],["praveen",125],["pramod",55]]
schema=["name","age"]

spark_123=spark_session_initalization()

df=spark_123.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()

### add a new colum 
marks_list=[[20,30,40],[50,60,70],[80,90,100]]

### but getting error
for i in marks_list:
  df=df.withColumn("marks",array(lit((I))))
```

[image]

I want like this

[image]

Comment: You want Marks to be a String or Struc ("Array") column?

Comment: string type @LuizViola

Comment: You would need to specify an index or a logic between the df and the list because the order of the rows is not deterministic

Comment: Kindly help me with the coding part?@LuizViola